# Make a theos tweak work with all user apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia, cydia-substrate

How can i make a tweak work with all user apps when startup the app and show a popup.

Instead of hook the view controller of every app .

I tried make a filter to "http://com.apple.UIKit" and tried to use “%ctor” but no thing happened .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into all apps be injecting into UIKit, without http

```
{
    Filter = {
        Bundles = (
            "com.apple.UIKit"
        );
    };
}
```